# How to insert a new field into my query using pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I want to be able to add a new field to the data that I'm querying from the main database.

If I run the following code below:

```
database_connection = MongoClient(database_address)
collection = database_connection.db.collection

id_list = [1,2,3,4]

leads_list = []

for i in id_list[0:2]:
    leads = list(collection.find({ 'prospects': int(i) }, {
        '_id':0,
        'created': 1,
        'prospects': 1,
        'tags': 1
        }
    ))
    leads_list.extend(leads)
```

I get this as a result:

```
[{'tags': [],
  'prospects': [1],
  'created': datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 5, 14, 59, 2, 782000)},
 {'tags': [],
  'prospects': [1],
  'created': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 15, 7, 19, 48, 449000)},
 {'tags': [],
  'prospects': [2],
  'created': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 6, 19, 36, 474000)},
 {'tags': [],
  'prospects': [2],
  'created': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 15, 17, 7, 59, 171000)},
 {'tags': [],
  'prospects': [3],
  'created': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 1, 32, 6, 953000)},
 {'tags': [],
  'prospects': [4],
  'created': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 7, 7, 3, 42, 54000)}]
```

I want to add a new field to it and get something like this:

```
[{'id': 1
  'tags': [],
  'prospects': [1],
  'created': datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 5, 14, 59, 2, 782000)},
 {'id': 1
  'tags': [],
  'prospects': [1, 23],
  'created': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 15, 7, 19, 48, 449000)},
 {'id': 2
  'tags': [],
  'prospects': [2],
  'created': datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 30, 6, 19, 36, 474000)},
 {'id': 2
  'tags': [],
  'prospects': [2, 34, 56],
  'created': datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 15, 17, 7, 59, 171000)},
 {'id': 3
  'tags': [],
  'prospects': [3, 35, 64],
  'created': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 28, 1, 32, 6, 953000)},
 {'id': 4
  'tags': [],
  'prospects': [4, 12, 46],
  'created': datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 7, 7, 3, 42, 54000)}]
```

Thanks again! words words words words words words

Comment: Do you want to get the **id** or not?

Comment: The **_id** and **id** are different.  I want the added field to follow the id_list. @JosuéCortina

Comment: @TheDodo, could you just use either [update_one()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) or [update_many()](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_many),  if you know the documents that you're querying ?